# methods of SKPhysicsContactDelegate is not being called

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

It seems that if two physic bodies have their `dynamic` property set to `false`, it is impossible to make them invoke `didBeginContact` method from `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`.

Long story short, the following code invokes `didBeginContact` method

```
player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: player.size)
player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Util.CollisionContactCategory.Player
player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Util.CollisionContactCategory.Score | Util.CollisionContactCategory.World | Util.CollisionContactCategory.Pipe
```

but this code does not

```
player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: player.size)
player.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Util.CollisionContactCategory.Player
player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Util.CollisionContactCategory.Score | Util.CollisionContactCategory.World | Util.CollisionContactCategory.Pipe
```

Even though I am 100% sure that those two bodies contact, they do not produce a message. I have read on other posts that if two physics bodies are not dynamic, `didBeginContact` will not be called.

Is there a way around this? I mean is it possible to let them be non-dynamic and invoke `didBeginContact` at the same time?

Thanks!